# Detecting if a key (CTRL) is currently pressed without a KeyEvent in Java

Tags: java, ctrl

I need to be able to see if the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key is currently being pressed during the processing of a mouse event.  I have tried to use the KeyListener, but trying to use the mouse event and key event together is proving to be an issue because of focus issues.

What I am essentially trying to accomplish is selecting multiple objects using the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key like in Windows.

It would be much easier if, while in my mouse event, I could just check the status of the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key...

Can you do that in Java?

Thanks.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that most GUI list components have built-in support for multi-select (both contiguous and non-contiguous). For example `JList.setSelectionMode`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

MouseEvent extends from InputEvent, and I think that you can still get the modifiers from this object via `getModifiers()` to see if a ctrl key has been pressed. I've not tested this yet though.

Comment: Yes, you can get modifiers for a mouse event - I've done it.  Indeed, IIRC, on older JVM's right click was sent as CTRL+LeftClick.

Answer (score 12):

Use `getModifiers()` to detect the key pressed..

**eg:**

```
if ((event.getModifiers() & ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK) ==ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK) {
System.out.println("CTRL KEY PRESSED");
}
```